# filter reactions from specific users discord.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, discord.js, collectors

I am making a bot where players can challenge each other. After posting the challenge command, which involves listing the players they want to issue a challenge to, I have my bot get the discord ID's for each of those users.

Then I have the bot post in a challenges channel, listing the players and await the reactions from only those players that were challenged. I made a reaction collector to collect those reactions. I want to filter those reactions to only include the ones that were challenged to avoid random players from hijacking a challenge.

In the code below, uniquePlayersIDArray is an array of discord user ID's. I just want the bot to only collect reactions from users that are in that array.

I have tried using uniquePlayersIDArray.indexOf(user.id) to detect if the user is in the array. As shown below I've tried uniquePlayersIDArray.includes(user.id).

```
async function acceptQuestion() {

  const agree = "✅"
  const disagree = "❌"
  let msg = await message.channel.send(`A challenge has been issued by ${author}?\n\n**IF** you are listed above, please select one of the following to accept or deny the challenge...`)
  await msg.react(agree)
  await msg.react(disagree)

  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && uniquePlayersIDArray.includes(user.id);

  };
 const collector = await msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {

  console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`)

  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
  message.channel.send(`${reaction.user} has **accepted** the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
  } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
  message.channel.send(`${reaction.user} has **declined* the challenge! Please await 5 minutes to pass or for all challenged players to respond!`)
    }
    });

    collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
    }
```

I know this works without adding anything after ".includes(reaction.emoji.name)" in the filter statement, but it picks up all reactions then.

I just want all reactions from people that were not challenged to be ignored.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? As long as the reacting user's ID is in `uniquePlayersIDArray`, your filter should do the trick.

Comment: @slothiful But it isn't acknowledging any reaction. I had the author of the challenge and one of the ones that was challenged react and after the 15 seconds, it says it collected 0 reactions.

Comment: Log `uniquePlayersIDArray` to the console and make sure that it's what you expect.

Comment: @slothiful I solved that problem. I had the wrong value being pushed to the uniquePlayersIDArray array. Thanks for pointing out that possibility. Now I am having an issue with the ${reaction.users} in the if else statement regarding the reactions that are given. It says undefined instead of the username. I would like it to say the username of the person who accepted or denied. According to the docs for MessageReaction, I think I might need to use .fetchUsers but  am unsure what to put before that method. reacton.fetchUsers doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a MessageCollector to check if the author of the executor is the one reacting and use message.awaitReactions instead of createReactionCollector

```
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 500000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                        msg.channel.send(logSetup);
                            const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => m.author.id === msg.author.id, { time: 500000 });
                            console.log(collector)
                            collector.on('collect', message => {

                                message.channel.send("You clicked ✅");

                            })
                    } else {
                        msg.reply('You clicked ❌');
                    }
                })
```